# NSDecimalNumber how to determine if there is a fractional component

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

I have a use-case where I want to determine if an NSDecimalNumber in swift has a fractional component (other than 0).  I can truncate the decimal portion, but that involves creating a new NSDecimalNumber and I would like to avoid that if possible.

I am doing this in a computed property, so I would like for it to be as efficient as possible.  This is currently what my extension looks like in a playground:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func decimalNumberRoundedToDigits(withDecimals: UInt8, roundingMode: NSRoundingMode = NSRoundingMode.RoundPlain) -> NSDecimalNumber
    {
        // round to required decimals
        let disp = decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior(NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: roundingMode, scale: Int16(withDecimals), raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false));

        return disp;
    }

    //  Convert the least significant byte into a signed 8-bit integer
    // Currently just truncates the fractional portion - I would like
    // to test it instead and only round if there are decimals.
    var safeByteValue: Int8 {
        get {
            let bits = UInt8(decimalNumberRoundedToDigits(0).longLongValue & 0xFF);

            return Int8(bitPattern: bits);
        }
    };
}

// just a test loop for demonstration
for i in 0...256
{
    print(NSDecimalNumber(unsignedInt: UInt32(bitPattern: Int32(i))).safeByteValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the "use case"? Why does it matter whether there are fractional digits or not?

Comment: I am writing a computational app which relies heavily on bit patterns, like dealing with unsigned 32-bit integers or signed 64-bit longs, etc.  I have found that in NSDecimalNumber, sometimes the properties for E.G., longValue do not work correctly when there are decimals.  The problem always goes away when you round it - so I just wanted to avoid creating a new number every single time a user wants to see the signed 8-bit version of a number and only round when that is exactly what the user wants (hence the question, I can't tell if the number has been rounded yet).

Comment: You cannot do that without rounding. To check for fraction digits you need to check both the value of mantissa and exponent. Imagine mantissa equal to `1000000` and exponent either `-20` or `0`. You always have to round and then compare with the original number. There is no other safe way.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I can live with it.  I need correctness more than performance.  I was just hoping I hadn't found what I needed yet.

Comment: By the way, all the `longLongValue` methods with transform the `NSDecimalNumber` to a `double` first, trimming all the additional precision. Note that `NSDecimalNumber` uses decadic arithmetic, not binary. That means all computations are slower than with a `double`. I am not sure it's a good idea in an app which relies on bit patterns, that is, binary arithmetics.

Comment: When you say 'trimming additional precision', do you mean the numbers that a double can represent that are larger than what an UInt64 can hold, or is there more?  If so, I am okay with that - it's part of the API so caveat emptor I suppose.  I really just want to get the lower 64 bits of the number as best I can.  What I REALLY want is to use a better numeric class, but I haven't been able to find one available in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient this will be, but it does give you the answer:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    var hasFractionalComponent: Bool {
        return ("\(num)").unicodeScalars.contains(UnicodeScalar("."))
    }
}
```